# How to move from UIViewController to SplitViewController?

Tags: ios

I have one `UIViewController` on which I've placed a button and have a `SplitViewController`, when I move to `SplitViewController` on button click it works properly in Simulator, but when I run it on iPhone it gives me following error.

> 2015-12-08 15:28:54.069 Wazapper[1968:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'UISplitViewController''

This is my code block.

```
-(void)setupRootViewController:(BOOL) animated {
    NSString *storyboardName=@"Main";
    UIViewController *newController = nil;
    UIStoryboard *board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewAnimationOptions transition = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone;
    newController = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UISplitViewController"];

    if (animated) {
        [UIView transitionWithView: self.window duration:0.5 options:transition animations:^{
            self.window.rootViewController = newController;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"setup root view controller finished");
            self.window.rootViewController = newController;
        }];
    }else{
        self.window.rootViewController = newController;
    }
}
```

[image: This is the screenshot]

Comment: set identifier for your splitviewcontroller in storyboard

Comment: i already set it, but still i am getting error please look at the screen shot, i edit my question again please look at this again

Comment: Where is your screen shot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693173/uisplitviewcontroller-viewidentifier-was-not-found-in-storyboard-error-with-io

Comment: Thanks man, the problem is come due to iOS versions.